# python class memory handling when inheriting an array from another class

Tags: python, arrays, class, pointers, inheritance

How does python class handle an array when the array is inherited from another class? Does the child class store the array from a parent class as a pointer or does it perform a deep copy and use up extra memory?

For example, if I had a code like

```
class parentclass(object):
 def __init__(self):
   self.parentarray = some array

class childclass(object):
 def __init__(self,parentclass):
  self.childarray = parentclass.parentarray

parent_cls = parentclass()
childclass(parent_cls)
```

does the program hold two of the same arrays or just one array with one pointer?

Thanks

Comment: Note that your example has nothing to do with inheritance. You just defined `childarray` as a reference to an object that is also referenced in another class. The classes have no inheritance relationship.

Comment: But doesn't child class inherit the parentclass since the parentclass is provided as an argument? How should the child class "inherit" the parent class to be considered as inheritance? @OskarHofmann

Comment: What you have isn't `parentclass` having any inheritance relationship with `childclass`, they are distinct classes with the same parent `object` (i.e. they are siblings in terms of class inheritance), just that the way you structured it, the `childclass` has a constructor that takes an instance of `parentclass` and assign the array from that `parentclass` instance to the new instance of `childclass`, and that underlying array is now assigned to two locations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general rule in Python is that assignment almost never makes a copy.  You just end up with two names to the same array object.

It's easy to test, if you make a modification to the one array you'll see the same change in the other.

Comment: You could also use id() to show the address of each object and will see that they are indeed to same.